# oracle SQL - show a number on multiple blank digits

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm having this problem , basicly I have a number 350 and I need to show it on 10 digits like this 350$$$$$$$ (I need to complete the number value with the character '$'). Thanks.

Comment: Huh?  "$" is not a digit.  Please clarify

Comment: Ok , so I have to show the number(350) on 10 digits  which is 3 digits in total and then complete the value or string or whatever with '$'. I can't explain it more.

Comment: Please explain more on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select rpad('350',10,'$') from dual
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I reward you? this is the first time i'm asking a question on this website.

Comment: just click on the 0 between the up/down arrows to the left.

Comment: Looks like I need to wait 5 mins before I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate the values as $ is not number for example

```
select 350 ||'$' from dual
```